# I'm trying to use QTabBar::pane stylesheet from official Qt 4.8 docs

Tags: c++, css, qt

I read topic about qstylesheet and tried to implement it in my app.

```
tabsMain->setStyleSheet(
"QTabWidget::pane {"
"   background-color: red; background-image: url(:/prefix1/images/patern.png); "
"   background-position: top left;"
"   background-repeat: repeat-xy;"
"}"
"QTabBar::tab:selected, QTabBar::tab:hover {"
"   background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,"
"                               stop: 0 #fafafa, stop: 0.4 #f4f4f4,"
"                               stop: 0.5 #e7e7e7, stop: 1.0 #fafafa);"
"}"
);
```

But nothing was changed. I tried to locate this item in the sources of Qt 4.8.1 (processing of style "QTabBar::pane") and that was all what I found:

QtSDK\QtSources\4.8.1\src\gui\styles\qstylesheetstyle.cpp

```
276:      QStyle::SC_None, "pane"
```

It's not implemented in this version of Qt or maybe in my OS only?

Comment: Try to read docs: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar ... If nothing happens - then you MUST set a border property in QSS. This is a "feature" of Qt styles on windows.

Comment: Big thanks, Dmitry! I added border-top property and got exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect of stylesheets on Qt widgets depends on the selected QStyle.

When using your example stylesheet on a QTabWidget in Qt designer, the widget's pane is colored correctly in all QStyles except the GTK+-style and the Cleanlooks-style.

Comment: I forgot to add that my OS is Windows (impossible to use unix machine, due to 3rd party library created with COM technology), so GTK+ can not explain this issue. As I mentioned before, nowehere in the Qt sources I can not find string 'pane'. I will now try lookup processing of this style in the sources of Qt5 for linux/mac and win and Qt4 for linux/mac.

Comment: The "pane"-line you found in `qstylesheetstyle.cpp` is just a definition of the pseudo element `PseudoElement_TabWidgetPane`, so you should search for that string.

Comment: Yea, you right! Elements in the enum PseudoElement corresponds to elements of the array knownPseudoElements of struct PseudoElementInfo. So, I decided to study for the problem in the sources of QTabWidget.